# Importing kml geospatial data into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson

I have found a source for geo data that represents a country, and its constituents. I am building a service where I would like to have a user select a country and then based on that country select an area they would like results from. I am trying to download the data and import it into MongoDB but I am unsure which file format is best to download, and what tools I will need to convert the data to import it. The file options are `ESRI file geodatabase`, `Shapefile`, `R file`, `Google Earth (.kmz)`, `Geopackage`, and `ESRI personal geodatabase`. Which one do I choose and what tools do I need for the next step? Is this even the correct approach to having the collection of countries and their states/territories?

Here is the open source data
[gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses a subset of the GeoJSON format for its geo-spatial data. I would look at which formats are closest to that. A quick web-search turned up [this tool](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson) for converting kml files to GeoJSON.